# Exclude underscore from word boundary in regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre, word-boundary

I'm using regex word boundary \b, and I'm trying to match `foo` in the following `$sentence` but the result is not what I need, the `underscore` is killing me, I want underscore to be word boundary just like hyphen or space:

```
$sentence = "foo_foo_foo foo-foo_foo";
              X   X   X  YES  X   X
```

Expected:

```
$sentence = "foo_foo_foo foo-foo_foo";
             YES YES YES YES YES YES
```

My code:

```
preg_match("/\bfoo\b/i", $sentence);
```

Comment: Have you tried searching online?

Comment: i cannot find this specific question on google

Comment: Are you able to use `preg_split` here instead of `preg_match`?

Comment: @Sunny There are articles online about this and the related questions section has many different questions relevant to his.

Comment: @sectus it must be preg_match :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would have to create [**DIY**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#diy) boundaries.

```
(?:\b|_\K)foo(?=\b|_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract `_` from the `\w` and use unambiguous word boundaries:

```php
/(?<![^\W_])foo(?![^\W_])/i
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K1J2Iv/1/). Note `\bfoo` = `(?<!\w)foo` and `foo(?!\w)` = `foo\b`, and subtracting a `_` from `\w` (that is equal to `[^\W]`) results in `[^\W_]`.

In PHP, you can use `preg_match_all` to find all occurrences:

```php
preg_match_all("/(?<![^\W_])foo(?![^\W_])/i", $sentence)
```

To replace / remove all occurrences, you may use `preg_replace`:

```php
preg_replace("/(?<![^\W_])foo(?![^\W_])/i", "YES", $sentence)
```

See the [PHP demo online](https://3v4l.org/HjiTv):

```php
$sentence = "foo_foo_foo foo-foo_foo";
if (preg_match_all("/(?<![^\W_])foo(?![^\W_])/i", $sentence, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
// => Array( [0] => foo [1] => foo [2] => foo [3] => foo [4] => foo [5] => foo)
echo PHP_EOL . preg_replace("/(?<![^\W_])foo(?![^\W_])/i", "YES", $sentence);
// => YES_YES_YES YES-YES_YES
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this do what you want?:

```
preg_match_all("/foo/i", $sentence, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: no, because it will also match foobar and i only want full words